# Windows 8 GridView groups width

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have problem with my gridview. I'm displaying grouped data in it and using `VariableSizedWrapGrid` for displaying items. The problem is that every group has the same width equal to the most item. Even if a group contains only 1 item it has width like it was 20 items there. How to make these ItemsPanels have variable width?

My issue is almost the same as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890033/how-to-create-variable-sized-group-panels-to-fit-the-items-in-windows-8-xaml) but when I use `VirtualizingStackPanel` as `GridView.ItemsPanel` my `VariableSizedWrapGrid` is displayed in one row and I need it to be displayed in two rows.

```
<SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                    <GridView ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False" 
                              ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="False"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PatientMediaFileBigItemTemplate}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PatientVisits} }" 
                              IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                              SelectionMode="None"
                              Margin="0,0,0,0" ItemClick="MediaFileIcon_Click"
                              >
                        <GridView.GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle>
                                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button Content="{Binding DateOfVisit, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter},  ConverterParameter='{}{0:dd MMM yyyy}'}" FontSize="28" Foreground="Black" BorderThickness="0" Click="ButtonVisit_OnClick"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0" Width="Auto"  Background="BlueViolet"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </GroupStyle.Panel>
                            </GroupStyle>
                        </GridView.GroupStyle>
                    </GridView>
                </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change the `ItemsPanel` of your `GridView` to a `StackPanel`, but note this will limit the number of items you can put in your `GridView` as it disables virtualization. A better option might be to keep showing a limited number of items in a group, but add a button (really the group header button with a chevron glyph should work) to navigate to a full view of the selected group.